# jQuery fade in/out on web app

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I have used Padilicious to allow a swipe on my homepage of an ipad webapp to load the news page but what I want to do is have the homepage fade out when the user swipes and then the news page fade in when it loads. I know how to get the news page to fade in but cannot get the homepage to fade out when the swipe is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply using the [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function?

```
$("#containingDiv").fadeOut()
```

So putting this into the code from padalicious you would have something like this which fades out when someone swipes to the right - but you can easily move it around that function

```
function processingRoutine() {
    var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);
    if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
        // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
        swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
        // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
        $("#containingDiv").fadeOut()
        swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else if ( swipeDirection == 'up' ) {
        // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
        swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'maroon';
    } else if ( swipeDirection == 'down' ) {
        // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
        swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris Yep I have but since the page needs a trigger to fade the content out, I'm not too sure as to how I use the fadeOut with my swipe detection. Currently if I use fadeOut() The page will immediately fade upon load.

Comment: How do you detect swipes at the moment? I presume this is a site for use on iPad / iPhone?

Comment: These lines are what i'm using at the end: ` if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/news.html';